# MySQL Alias Question

Tags: mysql, sql, alias, mysql-error-1054

i am wondering why this fails

```
mysql> SELECT Continent C, Name, SurfaceArea
    -> FROM Country
    -> WHERE SurfaceArea = (
    -> SELECT MAX(SurfaceArea)
    -> FROM Country
    -> WHERE Continent = C);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'C' in 'where clause'
```

its a answer provided by the certification guide for some sample exercises.

btw, for alias when do i have to use AS? isit optional?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to execute a correlated subquery, you need an alias for the outer **table**. You created an alias for the outer table's **field**. Take a look at the corrected code below, that has an alias for the table (Cou) that is referenced in the subquery (note that the field alias is not required so I removed it. There's no harm in adding it back if you wish):

```
SELECT Continent, Name, SurfaceArea
FROM Country Cou
WHERE SurfaceArea = 
(
    SELECT MAX(SurfaceArea)
    FROM Country
    WHERE Continent = Cou.Continent
);
```

Regarding the usage of AS, it's optional. For example, in the query above you could write `Country AS Cou`, it would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it has something to do with you're MySQL version. I just tested *exactly* the same query and it succeeds (syntaxically at least). Thats with *MySQL 5.0.45*.

If the MySQL version is not the issue, you could also try retyping the query. It may sound silly but sometimes *unprintable* characters may slip in your query while typing or copy/pasting (I'm thinking copy/paste from a PDF here, especially, since it's from a guide).

And, yes, `AS` is optional for aliases.